# Booting Windows Installer on separate Partition via Grub2

Tags: windows, boot, grub, opensuse, grub2

I have the following (dumb) Problem: I have set a BIOS Supervisor password on my Laptop and forgot it. Because I have a modern ThinkPad a BIOS password reset is not possible without desoldering chips or changing the mainboard.

However I want to install Windows. My plan: Download Windows ISO -> Mount ISO -> Copy files to ntfs partition -> Install Windows on separate ntfs partition. The last part is where my problem currently lies:

In order to install Windows from that partition I need to boot into it with grub2, so I created a custom boot entry in `40_custom`:

```
menuentry 'Windows ISO' {
set root=(hd0,6)
insmod ntfs
chainloader +1
}
```

But I tried multiple configurations like `set root=(nvme0n1,6)`, `set root=(hd0, msdos6)`, `chainloader /bootmgr`, `chainloader /bootmgr.efi`, altering the order of these commands, `insmod part_gpt`, ... . But I think (hd0,6) is right because grub produces the following output:

```
grub> ls (hd0,6)
Filesystem unknown.
```

I also tried running `insmod ntfs` and `insmod ntfs.mod` before `ls (hd0,6)`: No change.

Because I am a Grub noob I am lost at this point. I am looking forward to your help. :)

FYI: [My Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4eOB.png), I am currently on openSUSE Leap 15.2.

Answer (score 0):

Get in terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add code down `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` Ctrl+O, enter, Ctrl+x

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot

Sorry 4 my speak, i'm russian)))

Comment: Unfortunatly that does not help. BTW isn't `sudo update-grub` a command for grub and not grub2? The grub2 command is `grub2-mkconfig`.